# non-blocking keyboard input

Tags: python, linux

Im building a p2p system when the peers are constantly listening for incoming connections (new peers) and sending commands through the terminal (user input) to the other peers. I am having difficulty looking for user input from the keyboard while always looking for new peers.

```
print 'Listening...'
while not shutdown:
    while sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]: #look for keyboard input... not working
      line = sys.stdin.readline()
      if line:
        send_message(line)
      else: # an empty line means stdin has been closed
        print('eof')
        exit(0)

    try: # listen for other peers
        clientsock,clientaddr = mySocket.accept()
        print 'Incoming connection from', clientaddr
        clientsock.settimeout(None)
        t = threading.Thread( target = HandlePeer, args = [clientsock] )
        t.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "shutting down"
        shutdown = True
        continue
    except Exception,e:
        print 'error in peer connection %s %s' % (Exception,e)

mySocket.close()
```

HandlePeer checks for incoming messages from the newly connected peer. I just need a way of sending messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you'll need to use [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html).

Its a lot more difficult than just calling `input()` and receiving a response, but it is what you'll need. There is a good resource called [Curses Programming with Python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html#curses-howto) which is the best place to start.